# Does Dagger 2 Increase the APK Size?

Tags: android, dagger-2

How much size does Dagger 2 increase the android apk? As proguard removes unused methods, how do you track the actual increased size?

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio, and go to `File` > `Profile or Debug APK`. From there you explore your APK and get a breakdown of what parts are contributing what to the total APK size.